# .NET unable to connect to Oracle DB using Oracle proxy user

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am setting up a test version of my website against a new schema. I am trying to connect using the proxy connection and am getting the following error:

> ORA-28150: proxy not authorized to connect as client

my connect string has the following form:

> Data Source=*Instance*; User Id=*user*; Proxy User Id=*prxy_usr*;Proxy Password=*prxy_pass*; Min Pool Size = 0; Connection Timeout = 30

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e24280.htm#ORA-28150): Grant the proxy user permission to perform actions on behalf of the client by using the ALTER USER ... GRANT CONNECT command.

Answer (score 5):

EddieAwad's answer was correct but here is the specific code to run:

> ALTER USER *username* GRANT CONNECT THROUGH *proxyUserName*;

The THROUGH keyword is the part I couldn't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [ALTER USER documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4003.htm). You will find the CONNECT THROUGH clause there as well as some proxy users examples.